# Keyframes is not working in LESS mixin with LESSHat

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

Here is the standard CSS I am trying to produce but want to use a LESS Mixin to do the work. You can check the working demo with pure css [**here**](http://codepen.io/thehung1724/full/EagezB/)

**Pure CSS**

```
@keyframes rotate {
    0%{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}

@keyframes rotate-fix {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate-fix {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

I'm using the same mixin as in the [**following post**](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/102793/LESS-Keyframes-Mixin) which is shown below.

```
.keyframes(@name, @frames) {
    @-webkit-keyframes @name { @frames(); }
    @-moz-keyframes @name { @frames(); }
    @-ms-keyframes @name { @frames(); }
    @-o-keyframes @name { @frames(); }
    @keyframes @name { @frames(); }
}
```

I am using it like this:

```
.keyframes(rotate, {
    0%{
        .transform(rotate(0)); // This is transform mixin from LESSHat
    }

    100%{
        .transform(rotate(180));
    }
});

.keyframes(rotate-fix, {
    0%{
        .transform(rotate(0));
    }

    100%{
        .transform(rotate(360));
    }
});
```

However, it's not working. The animation of the button won't rotate. The code works fine when not including it as a mixin. Can anybody tell me what I'm missing here?

The generated CSS looks like this:

```
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  .....
}
@-o-keyframes rotate {
  .....
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate-fix {
  .....
}
@-o-keyframes rotate-fix {
  .....
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-fix {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate-fix {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to interpolate

like this:

```
    .keyframes(~'<keyframes-name>, <keyframes-definition>')
```

and take a look at [Less Hat docs keyframes section](https://github.com/madebysource/lesshat/blob/master/README.md#--keyframes).